# JavaScript Future Value Calculator

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript and even newer to this forum, so please excuse my lack of experience.

I am trying to make a future value calculator that takes in your initial investment, interest rate and years of investment and returns the future value.  I am not getting the expected results when I input my values. I was hoping someone could take a look at my code and point out my error in logic. I'm still wrapping my head around how to think about code.

```js
"use srtict";

var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var calculateFV = function(investment, rate, years) {
 var futureValue = investment;
 for (var i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
  futureValue = futureValue + (futureValue * rate / 100);
  futureValue = futureValue.toFixed(2);
  return futureValue;
    }
 futureValue = parseFloat(futureValue); 
};


var processEntries = function() {
 var investment = parseFloat($("investment").value);
 var rate = parseFloat($("rate").value);
 var years = parseFloat($("years").value);
 $("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment, rate, years);   
};

window.onload = function (){
 $("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
 $("investment").focus();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Future Value Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="future_value.css">
    <script src="future_value.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Future Value Calculator</h1>
        
        <label for="investment">Total Investment:</label>
        <input type="text" id="investment"><br>
        
        <label for="rate">Annual Interest Rate:</label>
        <input type="text" id="rate">%<br>
        
        <label for="years">Number of Years:</label>
        <input type="text" id="years"><br>
        
        <label for="future_value">Future Value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="future_value" disabled><br>
        
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>      
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include the expected results and what you’re currently getting? `calculateFV` probably shouldn’t have a `toFixed` (which turns your number into a string) nor a `return` (which exits the function) inside the loop, though.

Comment: In your "calculateFV" function, you are returning "futureValue" from within your for loop. Remove that line; simply return "futureValue" after your line "futureValue = parseFloat(futureValue);"

Comment: @ChrisCousins Thank you so much for your response. 
When I  move "return futureValue;" after  "futureValue = parseFloat(futureValue);" the Calculate button no longer does anything.

Comment: @Ry- Thank you for your response. I moved "toFixed" and "return" out of the loop  and it's working now!

Comment: @ChrisCousins 
I moved "toFixed" out of the loop and it now works as expected.
Thank you!